# Frustrating XML Error, Flex, & OpenX

Tags: xml, apache-flex, openx

I'm trying to get Flex and OpenX to work together.

OpenX is returning XML. I've got two Flex classes that clean-up the XML and place the ads on my site (thank you Daryl Bowden). Unfortunately, I get Error #1090: XML parser failure, when I test it. And I can't figure out why.

The first class is:

```
package com.darylbowden.ads
{
 import mx.controls.Alert;

 public class Ad extends Object {
  private var _clickURL:String;
  private var _mediaSource:String;
  private var _target:String;
  private var _flash:Boolean;

  public function Ad(xhtml:XML, flash:Boolean = false) {
   super();
   _flash = flash;
   _parse(xhtml);
  }

  private function _parse(xhtml:XML):void {
   if(!_flash) {
    _clickURL = xhtml.a.@href.toString();
    _mediaSource = xhtml.a.img.@src.toString();
   }
   else if (_flash) {
    _mediaSource = xhtml.div.embed.@src.toString();

    var clickIndex:uint = _mediaSource.indexOf('clickTAG=', 0);
    _clickURL = _mediaSource.substring( clickIndex+9, _mediaSource.length);
   }
  }
  public function get clickURL():String {
   return _clickURL;

  }

  public function get mediaSource():String {
   return _mediaSource;
  }

  public function get target():String {
   return _target;
  }

 }




}
```

The second class is:

```
package com.darylbowden.ads
{
  import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
  import mx.controls.Alert;

 public class OpenAds {

   private static var externalCallback:String = "callOpenAds";
   private static var retries:uint = 10;

   public function OpenAds(){ 
   }

   public function getAdReturn():Ad {
    var xmlReturn:XML;
    if(ExternalInterface.available) {
     var adReturn:String = ExternalInterface.call(externalCallback);

       try

       {
       adReturn = adReturn.replace("//]]>->","//]]>->\n");
       var infoTagsIndex:int = adReturn.indexOf('<script type="text/javascript" src=""', 0);
       adReturn = adReturn.substring(infoTagsIndex, adReturn.length);
       var wasFlash:Boolean = false;
        if(adReturn.search("<embed") == -1) {
         adReturn = adReturn.replace('></a>', '></img></a>');
         adReturn = adReturn.replace('></div>', '></img></div>');
        }
        else {
         adReturn = adReturn.replace('></div>\n<script','></embed></div>\n<script');
         adReturn = adReturn.replace('></div>\n<noscript','></img></div>\n<noscript');
         wasFlash = true;
        }

      adReturn = '<adXMLReturn>' + adReturn + '</adXMLReturn>';
      xmlReturn = new XML(adReturn);

      var ad:Ad;

        if(wasFlash){
         ad = new Ad(xmlReturn, true);
        }
        else {
         ad = new Ad(xmlReturn);
        }
      }
      catch(error:Error){
       Alert.show(error.message + 'stacktrace: ' + error.getStackTrace(), "Error"); 
      }
    }
     else {
     Alert.show("Javascript must be enabled to view this page properly.", "Javascript Not Detected");
     xmlReturn = new XML('<root>xml</root>');
    } 
     return ad; 
    }

 } 



}
```

This is the what OpenX returns:

```
var OX_28140bee = '';
OX_28140bee += "<"+"a href=\'http://www.dcscore.com/openx/www/delivery/ck.php?oaparams=2__bannerid=1__zoneid=4__cb=42492045be__oadest=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.joeblow.com\' target=\'_blank\'><"+"img src=\'http://www.joeblow.com/openx/www/delivery/ai.php?filename=mybanner.png&contenttype=png\' width=\'468\' height=\'60\' alt=\'\' title=\'\' border=\'0\' /><"+"/a><"+"div id=\'beacon_42492045be\' style=\'position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; visibility: hidden;\'><"+"img src=\'http://www.joeblow.com/openx/www/delivery/lg.php?bannerid=1&amp;campaignid=1&amp;zoneid=4&amp;loc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dcscore.com%2F&amp;cb=42492045be\' width=\'0\' height=\'0\' alt=\'\' style=\'width: 0px; height: 0px;\' /><"+"/div>\n";
document.write(OX_28140bee);
```

Unfortunately, I can't figure out what the error is. Any suggestions? I'm ready for a lobotomy.

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

/////////////////////

As Antti suggested, I traced adReturn. Please see below:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--//<![CDATA[
   var m3_u = (location.protocol=='https:'?'https://www.dcscore.com/openx/www/delivery/ajs.php':'http://www.dcscore.com/openx/www/delivery/ajs.php');
   var m3_r = Math.floor(Math.random()*99999999999);
   if (!document.MAX_used) document.MAX_used = ',';
   document.write ("<scr"+"ipt type='text/javascript' src='"+m3_u);
   document.write ("?zoneid=4");
   document.write ('&amp;cb=' + m3_r);
   if (document.MAX_used != ',') document.write ("&amp;exclude=" + document.MAX_used);
   document.write (document.charset ? '&amp;charset='+document.charset : (document.characterSet ? '&amp;charset='+document.characterSet : ''));
   document.write ("&amp;loc=" + escape(window.location));
   if (document.referrer) document.write ("&amp;referer=" + escape(document.referrer));
   if (document.context) document.write ("&context=" + escape(document.context));
   if (document.mmm_fo) document.write ("&amp;mmm_fo=1");
   document.write ("'><\/scr"+"ipt>");
//]]>--></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.dcscore.com/openx/www/delivery/ajs.php?zoneid=4&amp;cb=46672151726&amp;charset=UTF-8&amp;loc=http%3A//www.dcscore.com/"></script><a href="http://www.dcscore.com/openx/www/delivery/ck.php?oaparams=2__bannerid=1__zoneid=4__cb=5f5d8fcb97__oadest=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dcscore.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.dcscore.com/openx/www/delivery/ai.php?filename=mybanner.png&amp;contenttype=png" width="468" height="60" alt="" title="" border="0"></a><div id="beacon_5f5d8fcb97" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; visibility: hidden;"><img src="http://www.dcscore.com/openx/www/delivery/lg.php?bannerid=1&amp;campaignid=1&amp;zoneid=4&amp;loc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dcscore.com%2F&amp;cb=5f5d8fcb97" width="0" height="0" alt="" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;"></div>
<noscript></noscript>
```

I still don't see the error. Hopefully someone will see the problem.

Thank you.
-Laxmidi

Answer (score 0):

Try tracing out adReturn before creating an XML object from it (parsing xml). Then run the result through an XML parser which most likely should give you a good idea of what's wrong.

Comment: Hi Antti,

Thank you for the suggestion. I traded out adReturn and posted it as an edit. Unfortunately, I still don't see the error.

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Comment: @Laxmidi, Trace out adReturn after you've done your manipulations to it, right before the new XML() call.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read all your code, but judging from your sample output I think your problem is that Flash needs a single root node to parse something as XML, your data has whole bunch of them. 
Wrap them in a single tag and it should work.